# vb.net cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Error at dvgColumnz and rowData saying u cannot convert 1-d array of string, anyone know whats the problem? need help..

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
    sfd.FileName = "Quotation-csv"
    sfd.Filter = "CSV File | *.csv"

    If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(sfd.FileName)

            Dim dgvColumnz As List(Of String) = gridData.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList().Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()

            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", dgvColumnz))

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gridData.Rows

                Dim rowData As New List(Of String)
                For Each Column As DataGridViewColumn In gridData.Columns
                    rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(Column.Name).Value))
                Next
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowData))
            Next


        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You've got one-too-many ToLists in there. You don't actually need *any*: `Dim dgvColumnz = DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).Select(Function(c) c.Name)` will create an IEnumerable(Of String), which can be used in String.Join.

Comment: The question is tagged with visual-studio-2008 - are you really using that version?

Comment: Yes, im using 2008 because my supervisor asked me to

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you, the '''dvgColumnz''' has been fixed, what about '''rowData''' ? i dont think there is too many ToLists there.

Comment: The code in the question for `rowData` worked when I tried it. You could use `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gridData.Rows` `sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value)))` `Next`.